# Trouble installing Unity8-LXC on Mint

Tags: linux-mint, apt, dependencies, lxc, unity

(I originally posed this on askubuntu but was told it should be here instead.)

I want to install `unity8-lxc` on Linux Mint so I can check out Unity8 without installing it. Mint 17.3 (Rafaela) of course uses Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, the latest kernel supported by which is 3.19 (I think we're on kernel version 87.32 now?).

Since Mint is basically Ubuntu, I did:

```
apt-add-repository ppa:unity8-desktop-session-team/unity8-preview-lxc
apt update
apt install unity8-lxc
```

which gives:

```
[...]
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unity8-lxc : Depends: python3-lxc but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

naturally, I did

```
apt install unity8-lxc python3 -f
```

which yields:

```
[...]
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-lxc : Depends: liblxc1 (= 1.1.2-0ubuntu3~ubuntu14.04.1~ppa1) but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: lxc-templates (>= 0.8.0~rc1-4ubuntu43) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

and

```
apt install unity8-lxc python3-lxc liblxc1 lxc-templates
```

gives

```
[...]
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 liblxc1 : Depends: libcgmanager0 (>= 0.28) but 0.24-0ubuntu7.5 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

despite the fact that as far as my scouring of the internet can tell, .24 is the latest available version of `libcgmanager0`. I built it from source, but I still get this issue.

Lastly,

```
apt install unity8-lxc python3-lxc liblxc1 lxc-templates libcgmanager0
```

returns

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libcgmanager0 is already the newest version.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 liblxc1 : Depends: libcgmanager0 (>= 0.28) but 0.24-0ubuntu7.5 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any advice? Or should I give up...

*Edit:* I installed `unity8` from `community.linuxmint.org` and I have a shell window but it's pretty broken...

Comment: I can confirm the exact same problem on a stock Ubuntu 14.04, with installed Mate desktop. I guess maybe it is something there that requires libcgmanager0? I tried `apt-cache rdepends libcgmanager0`, but it didn't tell me much...